# Salvar form-data em webapi C#

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

Eu tenho o seguinte código em Angular 2 para um método post de form-data:

```
    upload(event) {
      let files: FileList = event.target.files;
      let formData = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        formData.append('attachment', files[i], f.name);
      }
     //call the angular http method
     this.http.
       .post(URL, formData)
       .map((res:Response) =>
          res.json()).subscribe(
             (success) => {
             alert(success._body);
          },
       (error) => alert(error))
      }
   }
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente mandando tudo que eu gostaria, meu problema agora está na criação da API em C#, qual o tipo que eu receberei no back compatível com FormData? Como eu o manipulo? Há possibilidade de salvá-lo no banco? Se não, como salvar em uma pasta? Agradeço toda ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei este no WebApi em C# e funcionou muito bem.
Peguei esta informação um tempo atrás do prórpio StackOverFlow aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965568/webapi-file-uploading-without-writing-files-to-disk

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }        

    var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

    foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
    {
        var fileBytes = await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Consegui ler a informação agora, já marcarei como correta sua resposta, mas como dúvida: ao salvar como array de byte no banco, como no futuro você busca e o converte?

Comment: Tudo depende de como você está gravando todo o conteúdo. Pois para "facilitar" eu gravo o nome do arquivo e tipo, aí retorno um objeto com os dados para montar.

Comment: Se não for pedir demais, você tem algum exemplo de montagem desse objeto? Pois tenho receio em gravar como `bite[]` e no retorno me bater para reconverter.

Comment: Eu não tenho mais o código em mãos, mas eu gravava o Mimetype e fazia mais ou menos assim para recuperar. 

var pdf = "data:" + MimeType + "; base64, " + byteArray;
window.open(pdf);

Caso seja uma imagem em uma tag é só fazer isso:

<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{imageAMostrar}}">

Comment: Bacana! Acho que a ideia é bom por aí mesmo, gravando o nome também. Obrigado por toda ajuda Marcio! Me poupou algumas horas.